# How to sum panda column by unique index, but then reset the sum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sum, pandas-groupby

New to Python. I have a pandas DataFrame as follows:

```
User_ID    Clicks
23         2
19         3
19         5
22         1
98         8
19         1
19         3
```

I want to sum the clicks for each User_ID but I want the sum to reset when the User_ID shows up again with a new row, like this.

```
User_ID    Clicks
23         2
19         8
22         1
98         8
19         4
```

Notice how User_ID 19's sum got reset when that ID appeared again.

So far I have:

```
df.groupby(User_ID)['Clicks'].sum().reset_index()
```

But it adds all of User_ID 19's clicks in just one row.

Answer (score 2):

By using `diff` and `cumsum` create the group key , then we using `agg`

```
df.groupby(df['User_ID'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()).agg({'User_ID':'first','Clicks':'sum'})
Out[1176]: 
         User_ID  Clicks
User_ID                 
1             23       2
2             19       8
3             22       1
4             98       8
5             19       4
```